# How can I improve this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[How can I make Haproxy do health-check for backup servers only if all non-backup servers are unavailable?](https://serverfault.com/questions/957592/how-can-i-make-haproxy-do-health-check-for-backup-servers-only-if-all-non-backup)

I don't know what is the reason to vote-down this question, can you all help me find out this possible vote-down reason?

Comment: Please don't edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers. You turned your question into a completely new one. You should ask a new question for this. You can refer to this question for reference if you feel the need to.

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to tell how many servers you're talking about and how they're used:

- how many is "lots" of backup servers
- what do you mean by "slower unstable-online" ?
- what does "unlikely unavailable" mean?  Did you mean likely?

Answer (score 6):

I just read the question, and I don't understand what you are looking for.

I was about to think that you mean backup server, to create a backup, but as I seen the tag haproxy so I guess it's for that product.

For me it's unclear as-is. Please edit to add detail.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bad question. It's clear enough for people who know well haproxy and they could surely answer it. The concept is technically valid. The problem with the question: it's very hard to parse for people who aren't versed in this particular area of haproxy config (i.e. the `backup` keyword).

Why are these people's understanding relevant? Well, here we care **mainly** about them - this site's main goal isn't to help you (brutally speaking). It's 1% to help you and 99% to help all other people who will google at some point for the same class of problems.

For the sake of them, try not to focus on `backup`. Because `backup` here is *also* a part of solution, *not* a part of the 'business' problem. Surely, after you re-visit the question (after some time) you'll find a way to express the problem in a way that is understandable to people who have many backends, use haproxy, have a limited throughput, but never used `backup` keyword yet.